# Database data encryption in SQL Server for web application

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, encryption, sql-server-2005

I am trying to saved the data in database table in encrypted format to hide the data store in the database table to be read by the user

Any advice how I can do this with out much effort on application level with less overhead on my application side?

Answer (score 1):

Read this [MS SQL Server Encryption Hierarchy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189586(v=sql.110).aspx)

Ex:

```
-- Open the symmetric key with which to encrypt the data.
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01
   DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE HumanResources037;

-- Encrypt the value in column NationalIDNumber with symmetric key
-- SSN_Key_01. Save the result in column EncryptedNationalIDNumber.
UPDATE HumanResources.Employee
SET EncryptedNationalIDNumber
    = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SSN_Key_01'), NationalIDNumber);
```

[MSDN EcryptionByKey syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms174361(v=sql.110).aspx)